# How to access array outside of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, security, this

I'm just wondering how to figure this strange security/scope question out:

```js
function vector() {
    var array = [];
    return {
        append: function append(v) {
            array.push(v);
        },
        get: function get(i) {
            return array[i];
        },
        store: function store(i,v) {
            array[i] = v;
        }
    };
}
```

---

This is the question asked:

> Can you spot any security concerns with this approach? Mainly, can we get access to the `array` outside of `vector`? Note*: the issue has nothing to do with prototypes and we can assume that global prototypes cannot be altered. Hint*: Think about using `this` in a method invocation. Can we override a method of vector?

### Example

```js
var v = vector();
v.append(1);
v.append(2);
var internalData = exploitVector(v); // [1, 2]
```

#### My attempts  + thoughts

Pretty sure I'm supposed to use the `this` keyword somehow as the hint says.
I'm a beginner at javascript so I don't fully understand the `context` that well. This code is written in a file with other functions on the text editor Atom, not a browser.

```js
function exploitVector(v) {
    v.get = function() {
        return this.array;
    };
    console.log(v.get());
    return v.get();
}
```

Also, this is just a fun exercise I saw on a github repo.

Comment: Instead of this.array you should try window.array.  Where is the global array defined?  If it is a global variable it should be available in the function.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code, do not use image links for code or data.

Comment: @visibleman Sorry, I added the code and more information. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vector.store()` can be abused to modify the array methods (e.g. `array.push`), followed by a `v.append()` to trigger the modified `array.push` method. The modified push method can for example either do something like `window.visiblearray=this` after which, visiblearray can be accessed globally.

Or as in the example below, store `this` (Array instance) to visiblearray of local scope, and then return it.

```js
function vector() {
    var array = [];
    return {
        append: function append(v) {
            array.push(v);
        },
        get: function get(i) {
            return array[i];
        },
        store: function store(i,v) {
            array[i] = v;
        }
    };
}

var v = vector();
v.append(1);
v.append(2);
var internalData = exploitVector(v); // [1, 2]


function exploitVector(v) {
    var visible_array;
    v.store('push', function(x){visible_array=this}) // modify array push 
    v.append(12)                                     // trigger the modified array push
    console.log(visible_array);
    return visible_array
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm really surprised this works. I had no idea an array could store that strange `push` function. And I didn't know you could access the array's `push` variable using the dot syntax in `array.push`. Finally, the `push` that ended up getting used was the one in the array, rather then the original one, I wonder why that is? And the `this` as well was a pretty clever way to grab it.

Comment: For an object in JavaScript, member/method access can be done either by dot or bracket operator. A bit simplified, we can say that Array, is also a type of object, and if the bracket getter doesn't find the entry in the array data, it will search the object instance members and methods.